# Disabling the top navigation bar (breadcrumbs) in Sphinx ReadTheDocs theme

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I would like to disable the top navigation bar of the ReadTheDocs theme. For other theme, for instance `classic` it is just an option

```
html_theme = "classic"
html_theme_options = {
    "showrelbartop": False
}
```

How I can modify the read the docs theme to disable this top navigation bar?

**Edit:**
After processing the source files with `make html`, I have to remove these lines in html files

```
<div role="navigation" aria-label="breadcrumbs navigation">
  <ul class="wy-breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="index.html">Docs</a> &raquo;</li>
    <li></li>
      <li class="wy-breadcrumbs-aside">
      </li>
  </ul>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

to obtain the expected result. Is it possible to obtain this result before compiling the sources with `make html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you refer to the breadcrumbs (`breadcrumbs.html`). You can simply open the main template file - `layout.html` - and delete or comment out the following line:

```
{% include "breadcrumbs.html" %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already do it after the process that generates the files by removing some code. I will edit my question to make it clear. I want to do it before the generation of html files.

Comment: Please reconsider my answer: If you remove the include statement from the **template** file - layout.html, than it won't appear in your html output. The generated output is based on the template file, so you need to edit the template only once.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I needed this as well.  A simpler answer than the currently accepted one, which works for Sphinx==3.5.3 and sphinx-rtd-theme==0.5.2 is:

- in `docs/_templates/`, create a file called `breadcrumbs.html`
- in that file, write an html comment like `<!-- Empty override file take the place of env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx_rtd_theme/breadcrumbs.html, which generates the top nav breadcrumbs. -->`.

Rebuild, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like this, the empty override for `breadcrumbs.html` is breaking.

I have done it, and it broke my site for Google, since you break the site navigation for blind users, including web engines. They like to know where on the site they are. For me that became a JavaScript error, since variables were not set.

Instead do

```
.wy-breadcrumbs {
    display: none;
}
```

This left me with a `<hr>` in the HTML, that I didn't figure out how to hide in CSS, since I already have LXML in place for modifying the generated HTML code for more performance on my site.